# Two 500GB (JBOD) drives out of an NAS-200 put into UBUNTO 14-04 and put back into an LVM to access old information

Tags: partition, lvm, testdisk

I’m in a dilemma as I’m new to Linux (not helpless, but new) and would like some help if you don’t mind.  I have been working with Linux for several years to some extent so I can get around some with the GUI, DASH and Terminal etc.

Here is my story and I’m sticking with it! I have two drives that were JBOD in an NAS-200 drive.  Both work fine and both are in a UBUNTU 14.04 system and your software TestDisk sees both drives as well as the HDD used for the operating system. The Fdisk –ls output is shown below.

```
Eusa@LENOVO-XXXX:~$ sudo fdisk -ls
[sudo] password for rethierusa: 

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00044521

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758   625141759   312320001    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760   625141759   312320000   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdc: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x77ea33fe

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1              63   976045139   488022538+  8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sdc2       976045140   976527089      240975   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sdc3       976527090   976768064      120487+  82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0d1a028c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1              63   976045139   488022538+  8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sdb2       976045140   976527089      240975   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sdb3       976527090   976768064      120487+  82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 316.6 GB, 316586065920 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38489 cylinders, total 618332160 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 3208 MB, 3208642560 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 390 cylinders, total 6266880 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Your program TestDisk shows the following:

```
TestDisk 6.14, Data Recovery Utility, July 2013
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org> http://www.cgsecurity.org
TestDisk is free software, and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
Select a media (use Arrow keys, then press Ente):
 Disk /dev/sda - 320 GB / 298 GiB  Hitachi HDT725032VLA380

 Disk /dev/sdb - 500 GB / 465 GiB  HITACHI HDS725050KLA360

 Disk /dev/sdc - 500 GB / 465 GiB  HITACHI HDS725050KLA360

 Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  316 GB / 294 GiB - Hitachi HDT725032VLA380

 Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1  3208 MB / 3060 MiB - Hitachi HDT725032VLA380

 Disk /dev/dm-0 - 316 GB / 294 GiB  Hitachi HDT725032VLA380

 Disk /dev/dm-1 - 3208 MB / 3060 MiB  Hitachi HDT725032VLA380
```

My interest is to make an LVM out of the two 500GB drives so I can retrieve my information.  Is this possible and could you point me to a link or steps to do this?  One of the things is that I don’t know which drive is to be first in line if there is a preference.  I do know which drive is which by using Disks which gives me the serial numbers of each drive.

Know understanding fully the workings of the LVM’s I don’t know if there is a sequence each drive is to be placed to attach to the other drive to make the Logical Volume?  Also, the two 500GB drives don’t show as active according to Fdisk so I guess neither are mapped so that a Logical Volume can’t be made up.  Disks shows both HDD as `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdc1` respectively both with a partition type as "Linux LVM" and Contents show as "LVM2 Physical Volume (LVM2 001)"  Disks goes on to show a graphic representation of Partition 1 with 500 GB LVM2 PV , Partition 2 with 247 MB LVM2, Swap Partition 3 with 123 MB Swap (Version 2 Non Active), Free Space 2.6MB.

Your help in this matter is greatly appreciated.  Also, I guess I should have asked if making a LV out of these two drives both out of a Linux based NAS-200 by Cysco originally Lynksys is possible.